# PHP query single line from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem echoing a single line from a sql query. I'm still pretty new at this but I can't figure it out at all.

I have a page titled "listing.php?id=7"

Inside the page is this script:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass"); 
    mysql_select_db("table"); 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        $year = $r["year"];
        $make = $r["make"];
        $model = $r["model"];
        $miles = $r["miles"];
        $pricepay = $r["pricepay"];
        $pricecash = $r["pricecash"];
        $transmission = $r["transmission"];
        $color = $r["color"];
        $vin = $r["vin"];

        echo "$year $make $model $miles $pricepay $pricecash $transmission $color $vin<br />";
    }
?>
```

The problem lies within "WHERE id='$id'". When I use a var, it displays nothing, but if I manually make it my ID number, example 7, it works fine. What's am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you indent text with at least four spaces, it will be formatted as code. Edit your question now and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your original code and add this line before the query:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id']; // Sanitize Integer Input
```

And change your query as others suggested to remove the quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id=$id";
```

I am assuming your `id` is a normal mysql `auto_increment` which starts at 1. That means if `$_GET['id'] is anything but a number, it will come back as 0 and thus not match anything in the database.

Answer (score 2):

if

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id=7
```

works but

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id='$id'
```

doesn't work 
then get ride of the quotes around $id

So

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id=$id
```

The quotes are turing $id into a string comparison - which won't work if the column type is integer.

Comment: It gives me the error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/sallyaut/public_html/temporary/listing.php on line 101.  Line 101 is: while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: Also move away from doing `SELECT * FROM`, it is inefficient, and creates problems if DB schemas are changed, define your requested elements (year, make, model, etc;).

Also ALWAYS sanitize your data when making `ANY` SQL queries (wether select or insert). Or you open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Noted, I understand the first part, but like I said, I am pretty new to this. What do you mean by sanitize my data?

Comment: MySQL will cast the string to an integer and carry on. The quotes are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Even better, use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO). Create the connection:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=someDBname", 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

but do it in just one script, preferably in a singleton or somesuch. This has many advantages, including placing all database passwords in one file (which is easier to secure) and reducing the possibility of typos in the hostname, database name, username or password causing the connection to fail. Use it as:

```
try {
    $query = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT year, make, model, miles, pricepay,
                pricecash, transmission, color, vin 
           FROM vehicles WHERE id=?"
    );
    $query->execute(array($_REQUEST['id']));
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        echo implode(', ', $row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo "Query failed.";
}
```

This uses a [prepared query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which is not vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). It also [does away with "or die"](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die).

In case you haven't seen singletons, here's an example:

```
class DB {
    private static $db;
    static function open() {
        if (! isset(self::$db) ) {
            self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostName,dbname=dbName', 'user', 'password');
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need a connection, just call `DB::open()`. If you need to connect to multiple hosts, store PDOs in an associative array within DB, rather than DB::$db. In this case, you could put the connection information in the DB script, or put it in a separate configuration file that DB parses.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/sallyaut/public_html/temporary/listing.php on line 110

Comment: There was a typo in the exception handling block, but it's fixed now. You'll want to be able to catch typos like the one I made, so compare the before and after and make sure you understand what the error was about. Also make sure you read up on the PDO classes and prepared queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id=%d", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

1. I hope you don't have register globals on which means you should use $_GET['id'];
2. You can't put quotes around the `id` field if it's an `int` in your table
3. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent sql injection

Comment: $id in my table is an int. When I tried your script, it gave me an error of: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/sallyaut/public_html/temporary/listing.php on line 98

Comment: @Galen, your code has multiple errors. It is missing the string formatting option, and your myqsl_real_escape_string is missing parens, etc.